# #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql

I'm programming a Website with some friends, we code it on Php and public it on a vServer, our only problem is, that we get the error message on the top when we want to import the SQL File from our local phpMyAdmin. We are using Debian 8 on our Server and we don't know much about phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PhpMyAdmin, it's just a generic MySQL error.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Prior to 5.6, full-text search can only be used with MyISAM tables, not InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the SQL script you're trying to import, the FULLTEXT index is available for MyISAM tables prior to 5.6

Is the SQL script hand made?

Comment: It's the other way around. Before 5.6, it's only available for MyISAM.